# Java Runtime.exec() not sending emails as from the command line

Tags: java, linux, macos

I'm creating a java application and one of the features I would like to add is sending a generated email out to users. I have set up mail on my Macbook and I can send emails from the command line just fine. I'm having an issue sending emails when I call runtime.exec(). Anyone have any idea why it will not execute and send the emails?

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
    runtime.exec("echo This is the body | mail -s Subject -F myemail@gmail.com");
}
catch ( Exception e ) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I don't get any errors and everything compiles fine. I just don't get any emails sent out. If anyone could hel it would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Try to call the `Process proc = runtime.exec(...);` `proc.waitFor()...` and then print out the stream from the process to see if there is any error. [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Runtime.exec not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475497/runtime-exec-not-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Runtime.exec(String)` does not execute the entire string by pasting it into a UNIX shell and running it. This is because it's a huge security flaw.

Imagine you did this:

```
runtime.exec("Hello "+name+" | mail ...");
```

I could then set `name` to `; rm -rf /*; echo` or `&& cat /etc/passwd`, or some other shell injection code.

So, [Java is breaking up your command into parts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29):

> More precisely, the command string is broken into tokens using a StringTokenizer created by the call new StringTokenizer(command) with no further modification of the character categories. The tokens produced by the tokenizer are then placed in the new string array cmdarray, in the same order.

Ultimately, you are running the `echo` command alone, with parameters such as `|` and `mail`. The `echo` command will just print these out to standard output, which you don't collect. It will never invoke the `mail` command.

You shouldn't use the `mail` command to send mail from Java, due to the security risks involved. You should use the JavaMail package which provides a safe and convenient API for sending mail. The UNIX `mail` command works by connecting to a `sendmail` daemon running on the local machine on port 25, and JavaMail can do this too.

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

public class SendMail {
    public static sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String body)
        throws MessagingException
    {
        final Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
        final Message msg = new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(p));
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        msg.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(body);
        Transport.send(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to send an email to a user account on the intranet I am connected to. I understand this is only sending an email to a user on localhost. Is there any configuration I would need to make or just modify the p.put() method call?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you can turn on Mac OS X's local SMTP server, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1644540/3283598). A local MTA means that any local program can connect and ask for mail to be sent, whether it's for a local or remote user.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)?

Example usage:

```
private boolean sendMail(String host, String port, String user, String password,  List<String> toList, String htmlBody, String subject) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));

        // To get the array of addresses
        for (String to : toList) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));
        }

        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        try {
            transport.connect(host, user, password);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        } finally {
            transport.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This won't work when I can't use the Username/Password in my code or in any configuration file because of Compliance. Security team is urging to use mailx on the Unix system that is running, but executing through Runtime isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not spawning a shell and the | is a shell feature. An example that works:

Create a shell script and pass a command array to exec().

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      String[] cmd = { "sh", "send.sh", "This is the body", "Subject", "myemail@gmail.com"};
      runtime.exec(cmd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Shell script:

```
echo $1 | mail -s $2 -F $3
```

Comment: This didn't work. I wish it did cause I'm having a hell of a time setting up JavaMail haha

Comment: :). Oh, I tested it on my Linux laptop where it works. Maybe your shell is called differently, I learn from Googling that it's bash. Also make sure you place your script in the same directory as your class file, or add the full path in front of send.sh

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @ArnaudKleinveld. Above answers didn't considered the fact that in case if corporate world is blocking port 25 and 487 and you can only send mail through mail command then above solutions will not work at all.
But this will work.